# Symfony ChoiceType choice label isn't accepting string as a value

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

It would seem as though there is either a bug or documentation is wrong. Just posting this here to confirm this is a bug. ChoiceType::class

```
$choice1 = new \stdClass();
$choice1->name = 'Shipping';
$choice1->label = 'Shipping for you';
$choice1->code = 'xyz';

$builder
  ->add('modeOfDelivery', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices' => [
        $choice1
    ],
    'choice_label' => 'label',
    'choice_value' => 'code'
  ])
;
```

When trying to use a string as the value for choice_label I get this php error: `Expected argument of type "null or callable", "string" given`

in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php at line 70  -

```
    public function __construct($choices, $value = null)
    {
        if (null !== $value && !is_callable($value)) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($value, 'null or callable');
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing the choices_as_values option. This is required in version 2.8 to use objects as choices.